# Crystal Reports dateadd function error on interval

Tags: crystal-reports, dateadd

I have a date field on which my inventory item was bought.  Then I have a lifespan field in months eg 240.  Now I am trying to calculate the end of the item's lifespan date but I get an error:

```
numbervar myVariable := ({TABLE.LIFESPAN} * 30);
dateadd("d", myVariable,{@date})
```

I get the following error:  **"Date must be between year 1 and 9999"**

As soon as I change the variable to: `numbervar myVariable := {TABLE.LIFESPAN};` 
it works without any errors.  Also if I change the dateadd formula to `dateadd("d", 7200,{@date})` it works.

The format of the field TABLE.LIFESPAN is decimal(9,2) but none of the value has decimals, eg it will be 240.00

I have also tried

```
numbervar myVariable := Round({TABLE.LIFESPAN} * 30);
```

I suspect it has something to do with the decimals.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of `{TABLE.LIFESPAN} * 30`

Answer (score 1):

you will receive this value once your ({TABLE.LIFESPAN} * 40) causes the year to be greater than 9999. So if {@date} were today's date then {TABLE.LIFESPAN} could not be higher than 73955 or so. I would create a formula for ({TABLE.LIFESPAN} *40) and drop it on the canvas and see what that value is on all records and see if you have an unusually high number somewhere.

Comment: I used 40 by mistake but same principle. Your upper limit would be higher than 73955